# Show object details using WinUI 3.0 ListView with Grouped Headers

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3

I'm using the example code from the ListView with Grouped Headers demo in the WinUI 3 Gallery. I've gotten it to sort the items in my list perfectly, but when it shows them the Group Header shows properly but there is no data shown for each of the objects in the list. It just shows "[ProjectName.ObjectClassName]", i.e. "TestApp.Contacts".

I can't figure out how to actually show the information that is in that Contacts group as it is shown in the demo.

Here is the example XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsCVS.View, Mode=OneWay}">
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="ContactsCVS" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel AreStickyGroupHeadersEnabled="False"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle >
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local1:GroupInfoList">
                    <Border AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Key}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

And the C#:

```
public static async Task<ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>> GetContactsGroupedAsync()
{
    // Grab Contact objects from pre-existing list (list is returned from function GetContactsAsync())
    var query = from item in await GetContactsAsync()

    // Group the items returned from the query, sort and select the ones you want to keep
    group item by item.LastName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() into g
    orderby g.Key

    // GroupInfoList is a simple custom class that has an IEnumerable type attribute, and
    // a key attribute. The IGrouping-typed variable g now holds the Contact objects,
    // and these objects will be used to create a new GroupInfoList object.
    select new GroupInfoList(g) { Key = g.Key };

    return new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>(query);
}

// GroupInfoList class definition:
public class GroupInfoList : List<object>
{
    public GroupInfoList(IEnumerable<object> items) : base(items)
    {
    }
    public object Key { get; set; }
}

// Contact class definition:
public class Contact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
        public string Company { get; private set; }
        public string Name => FirstName + " " + LastName;

        public Contact(string firstName, string lastName, string company)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Company = company;
        }

    // ... Methods ...
}

ContactsCVS.Source = await Contact.GetContactsGroupedAsync();
```

And this is what it should look like:

[image: ListView with Grouped Headers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. In between `ListView.ItemsPanel` and `ListView.GroupStyle` I need to add the following section:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Contact">
        <Border AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Name}">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

That inserted the Contact.Name property instead of the name of the object. Microsoft doesn't include this in their documentation, as far as I can tell.